# Client-server app, где держат новости, которые с сервера возвращаются на запрос клиента

Tags: java, android

*Android client server app*, где держат новости, которые с сервера возвращаются на запрос клиента, чтобы после выхода из приложения они остались на некоторое время, и после входа на приложение эти новости отображались до нового запроса на сервер.

Предложите пожалуйста идеи про приложение новостей. Как организовать, где временно держать новости?

Использовать синглеты или *Sqlite* или еще есть варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite, но учитывайте, что новости должны будут чиститься(со временем), и Вам нужна будет база только для "отображения" данных новостей. Если Вы будете сохранять слишком много новостей - это будет оооочень плохо.